# How to combine other plugins with the JavaFX Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, javafx, plugins, pom.xml

I use the Git commit ID plugin together with the JavaFX Maven plugin. Unfortunately, the Git commit ID plugin "revision" goal is only executed by `mvn compile`, but not by `mvn javafx:compile` so I need to run both to successfully run my program. How can I get `mvn javafx:compile` to execute the "revision" goal of the Git commit ID plugin so that I don't need to double compile?

**Relevant POM Part**

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>[...]</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>[...]</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                <prefix>git</prefix>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                <format>properties</format>
                <gitDescribe>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <always>false</always>
                    <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                </gitDescribe>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Actually `javafx:compile` is using the Maven `compile` plugin internally. When you run `mvn javafx:run` if the project is already compiled, it won't compile again. So you can do `mvn compile` just once.

Comment: @JoséPereda: The problem is I still need to document this and everytime I do a `mvn` clean I need to compile it with both again.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question and post details of the Maven goals you want to run in one go?

Comment: @JoséPereda: It is the "revision" goal, I added it to the question as suggested.